# Clickhouse Aggregate data from one table into other table

Tags: sql, view, aggregate, materialize, clickhouse

i trying to solve this problem :

Given an *input_table* :

```
> app_name, user_id, state, timestamp \
> App1 ,   user1   , open,  1 \
> App1 ,   user1   , close, 2 \
> App2 ,   user2   , open,  3 \
> App1 ,   user4   , open,  4 \
> App2 ,   user3   , open,  5
```

I would like to using MV to update users and apps state mapping like the following *output_table*.

```
> App1 , [user4] -- user1 is closed \
> App2 , [user2, user3]
```

*output_table* should be updated as soon as data be inserted to *input_table*.

When i have incoming data in *input_table* like :

```
> App1, user5, open, 6 \
> App1, user1, open, 7
```

The output table is expected like this :

```
> App1 , [user4, user5, user1] \
> App2 , [user2, user3]
```

I have a very naive solution version but its a batch update and require table scan data to rebuild the mapping.
Is there any way we can do it partially after a short certain time or update by every row inserted. I think *Materialize View* can help, but iam not sure about the output table to be updated each insert in input_table

Answer (score 1):

As you are performing a GroupBy , if you do in a delta transaction, the resulted dataset will be applied on that delta part , not in the whole data, so in case your data is not huge the best way to perform in the whole table as below

```
SELECT app_name, GROUP_CONCAT(user_id) AS combined
FROM T
GROUP BY app_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Before using a materialized view I would suggest using the query over raw-data. To speed up this query consider defining the date range in *WHERE*-clause.

```sql
SELECT app_name, groupArray(user_id) users
FROM (
  SELECT app_name, user_id, argMax(state, timestamp) last_state
  FROM input_table
  WHERE timestamp BETWEEN 1 AND 11 /* <-- restrict the date range */
  GROUP BY app_name, user_id
  HAVING last_state != 'close')
GROUP BY app_name

/* result for 1st dataset
┌─app_name─┬─users─────────────┐
│ App1     │ ['user4']         │
│ App2     │ ['user3','user2'] │
└──────────┴───────────────────┘
*/
```

---

If this query will work slowly then need to use *Aggregated materialized view*.